# Highlight variables without $ inside (( )) when in sh-mode?

Tags: bash, sh-mode

Is there a way to modify `sh-mode` to highlight variables inside a double parentheses construct when not using the dollar sign prefix?
For example I want the `i` to be highlighted in `((i++))` without the need of writing `$i`.

Comment: My first impression is that this would require a re-write of `sh-syntax-propertize-function`. Note, that `((...))` can be a multiline-expression.